# How to build system for like and comment notification on particular post in mern app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io, push-notification

I want to build system like social media like and comment notification (fb notify to the post owner) in mern app . I am using socket.io for sending the notification . Its working , but I am confuse about how to send notification to only to the post owner .

1. How I can track post owner and send notification to him?
2. Does I need to create socket room for every post while creating new post and keep track the user(owner) and unique room for each post ?
3. Is there any other technique (socket.io) to build system like this ?

Comment: I think you're going in the right direction, since all Posts will have one unique thing about them that's the user-owner  *_id* in MongoDB, and yes you would have to have a separate room for each Post instead of all Posts because that's how you'd know which user's Post got a new like/comment. When user logs in they'll just join their rooms. And also if you were to implement a delete-post feature you should just remove that socket room from database for that particular Post.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the payload in the socket object inside the connection event.
Fetch all socket which is connected to the room.

```
io.on("connection", async(socket) => {
// Store user data inside socket object
socket.data = {
  userId:''
}

// Get all socket connected with room
const socketUsers = await io.in(roomId).fetchSockets();

/**
 * Find user which match with id
 * @id post creator id
 */
const postcreator = socketUsers?.find((userSocket) => {
  return userSocket.data.userId === id
})

// post creator socket id
console.log(postcreator.id)
});
```

Comment: @prathamesh is this answer satisfy your question?